# Changing the colour of a combobox in ZK

Tags: combobox, zk, zul

Hi I am a novice in ZK and I would like to change the selected cell of a combobox from light blue, the standard colour, to green. I have been looking for online resources but somehow I couldn't fine anything. Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to describe you wanted hover color to change not selected one. As of now the question and the answer do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing colors in ZK is done by apply/override css to the element.
The css class your looking for is `.z-comboitem:hover`.
Just add the following to the .zul

```
<style>
.z-comboitem:hover {
    background: /* your color here*/; 
 }
 </style>
```

Pleas read [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/CSS_Classes_and_Styles) for more information.

### EDIT

Sorry my answer is for changing the the hover color not the selected and the first version I refered to the wrong CSS class... 
**@kachhalimbus** answer should be the best, especially because he has for sure much more experience than me. So thanks to **@kachhalimbu** :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for i.e. selected item in the dropdown should be green instead of default light blue

```
<zk>
<style>
.z-combobox-rounded-pp .z-comboitem-seld, .z-combobox-pp .z-comboitem-seld {
    background: green;
}
</style>
<window border="normal" title="hello">
    <combobox>
      <comboitem label="item 1"/>
      <comboitem label="item 2"/>
      <comboitem label="item 3"/>
      <comboitem label="item 4"/>
    </combobox> 
</window>
</zk>
```

You can see a live demo of this [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/j7sbi/1-change-selected-comboitem-background) (with 6.0.1 breeze theme) but same code should work with ZK 6.5.1 freshly as well

Comment: Thanks for the help. However only the selected combo-item gets coloured green. If I move the mouse cursor over the different items of the combo-box, the colour of these items is still light blue (the standard polour)

Comment: So what color the hover should show instead of default one? I don't think you mentioned that in your original question and in the comment above. Do you want all of them to be green (selected and non-selected)?

Comment: Anyways Ignore my above comment. I just noticed you have already accepted the answer above :)